# Left join between two excel files in Tableau

Tags: excel, dashboard, tableau-desktop, tableau-cloud

I need to join two excel files in Tableau. One is master file, second file has some additional fields for some records so I can not do inner join instead I have to do Left join.

I was not able to find an option to do left join. I tried importing both excel and defining relationship but it inner join so did not solve the usecase.

Please suggest how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can Click the join icon to configure the join. Add one or more join clauses by selecting a field from one of the available tables used in the data source, choosing a join operator, and a field from the added table.

You have Left/Right options there itself

[image]

Answer sourced from : https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/joining_tables.htm